# Redux Firestore state not updating after adding or deleting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, react-router, google-cloud-firestore

Current Web App link: https://react-recycle.firebaseapp.com/

Item Component Code: https://github.com/steveula/react-recycle/blob/master/src/components/items/Item.js

redux-firestore API: https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore

**Note:** Quickly register an account with fake info and have React Dev Tools & Redux Dev tools installed to see the issue.

For my project, the recycled items from Firestore are in Item component cards, as you can see on the dashboard's sidebar. You can duplicate them and delete them. If you navigate to a page without Item components, say, Tips & Facts and then back to the dashboard, the Item component's functionality works just fine. If you look at the REDUX DEV TOOLS, you will see that `firestore.ordered.userItems` updates accordingly.

However, if you then navigate to a page that also has Item components, say, Statistics and then try to duplicate or delete them, the action will successfully update on the backend in Firestore, **but not in the redux state,** specifically `firestore.ordered.userItems`, so the props won't update, and so the UI will not rerender. *The problem no longer persists if you navigate to a page without Item components.*

I thought the problem had to do with the Listeners, so I tried using redux-firestore's `setListeners()` and `onSnapshot()` functions, but it hasn't been working.

What can I do to fix this issue?

(PS: Sorry if I'm not understanding something basic here. I'm new to react & firestore, and this is my first self-designed react project.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.

The way I solved it was setting a listener in a componentDidMount method and unset it in componentWillUnmount.

I'm not sure how did you try listener, but I hope this will help you out as I stuck on this for good day.

In your case:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.firestore.setListener({collection: 'users'})
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.firestore.unsetListener({collection: 'users'})
}
```

If you need you could set multiple listeners.